# Right Align Numeric Data in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

We all know T-SQL's string manipulation capabilities sometimes leaves much to be desired...

I have a numeric field that needs to be output in T-SQL as a right-aligned text column. Example:

```
Value
----------
   143.55
  3532.13
     1.75
```

How would you go about that? A good solution ought to be clear and compact, but remember there is such a thing as "too clever".

I agree this is the wrong place to do this, but sometimes we're stuck by forces outside our control.

Thank you.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The [STR function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189527.aspx) has an optional length argument as well as a number-of-decimals one.

```
SELECT STR(123.45, 6, 1)

------
 123.5

(1 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: Bravo! How did I miss this?
Do note that STR() takes a float, not a decimal. SQLServer Help is very explicit about it ("... an expression of approximate numeric (float) data type"): if your decimals have enough digits, rounding will cause you trouble.
This is still a great answer for most

Answer (score 1):

If you MUST do this in SQL you can use the folowing code (This code assumes that you have no numerics that are bigger than 40 chars):

```
SELECT REPLICATE(' ', 40 - LEN(CAST(numColumn as varchar(40)))) + 
CAST(numColumn AS varchar(40)) FROM YourTable
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to pad left:

```
CREATE FUNCTION PadLeft(@PadString nvarchar(100), @PadLength int)
RETURNS nvarchar(200)
AS
begin
return  replicate(' ',@padlength-len(@PadString)) + @PadString
end
go
print dbo.PadLeft('123.456', 20)
print dbo.PadLeft('1.23', 20)
```